# Spring boot java, use one property in another

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

This is a simplified example of what i am trying to achieve.

This is how the propertes file of my spring boot application looks like

```
someProp=4

command=java -jar -DdummyProp={someProp} hello.jar
```

I want value of someprop to be set dynamically (passed in from commandline) and that be plugged into another property (in this case into the property called command).

Can this be done without physically writing into the file (in memory)?

Comment: Sorry, I completely misread your question and edited it inappropriately. Hopefully I've fixed the damage I did.

Answer (score 2):

you can do this:

```
command=java -jar -DdummyProp=${someProp} hello.jar
```

Comment: It plugs in the value for dummyProp that is specified in the property file. I am setting dummyProp like this  System.setProperty("dummyProp", 6); But what it picks up is 4.